# How can I differentiate between fingerprints with TOUCH ID

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

Hello I would like to know how I can differentiate between two fingerprints to relate them to a user and password, because if I can not know who owns that footprint I could not relate them to a user within my app.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that's not currently possible. The result is authenticated or not, not authenticated by X.